# How to pass any value in parameterised query in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, parameterized-query

Objective: to pass any value in where phrase of mysqli parameterised query

code:

```
<?php
$name="%%";
$age="%%";
$name_op=null;
$age_op=null;
require_once("dbc.php");
$query="SELECT name, age from student WHERE name LIKE ? AND age LIKE ?";
$stmt=mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
mysqli_bind_param($stmt, "si", $name, $age);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_bind_result($stmt, $name_op, $age_op);
while(mysqli_bind_fetch($stmt)){
echo "name : $name_op age: $age_op";
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Observation:
In mysql prompt,

```
mysql> SELECT name, age from student WHERE name LIKE  "%%" AND age LIKE "%%";
```

shows all the records.

But, the above php code doesn't display any record.

Please help me in passing any value in parameterised query.

Comment: Why are you slowing down your query with these clauses anyhow?  Why not `SELECT name, age from student`?  Are you wanting to filter out `NULL` values?  Perhaps your sample data is making your question harder to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under "any" value you are assuming any *string* value. Hence, you must use the correct type: `s`, not `i` for the $age variable.

```
<?php
require_once("dbc.php");

$name="%%";
$age="%%";

$query = "SELECT name, age from student WHERE name LIKE ? AND age LIKE ?";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $age);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "name : $row[name] age: $row[age]";
}
```